# What's `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` in centos 7?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My system is centos 7 with mariadb 5.5.60.

```
####LOG####
log_warnings=1
log-error=/var/log/mariadb-err.log
####slow log####
slow-query-log=1
long_query_time=5
slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mariadb-slow.log
```

That 's all about `log` in my `/etc/my.cnf`.

I found `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` in my  server, but it's a empty file.
What's `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`?

Comment: Is the `mariadb` service running right now? Has it ever been running? Have you checked the log files specified in `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: `mariadb` is running well.other log files are everything ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log files are specified in the `/etc/my.cnf` file in your question. Upon a fresh installation, the error log is set as `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` and created at that location and is an empty file.

In yours, it is `/var/log/mariadb-err.log`. Either you or someone else changed that line in `/etc/my.cnf` before starting the service which is why the logs specified in `/etc/my.cnf` have data in them whereas `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` is empty. If you want logging to go to that file instead then all you need to do is change it in `/etc/my.cnf` and restart the service.